# Combining several XML documents sequential with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am trying to merge xml-documents from folder "files" into one DOMDocument, and create a table of contents.

The documents have the following structure:

```
    <chapter title="This is first chapter">
    <section title="This is the first section">
    <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
    </section>
    </chapter>
```

The following code is used for merging the XML-files:

```
foreach(glob("files/*xml") as $filename) {
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $first = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $first->formatOutput = true;
        $first->load($filename);

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;

    }
    else {


        $second = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');
        $second->formatOutput = true;
        $second->load($filename);
        $second = $second->documentElement;


        foreach($second->childNodes as $node)
        {

           $importNode = $first->importNode($node,TRUE);
           $first->documentElement->appendChild($importNode);
        }


        $first->saveXML();


        $xml->appendChild($xml->importNode($first->documentElement,true));


        }
    }

    print $xml->saveXML();
```

Everything seems to work OK, except a problem with `<chapter>`-elements. This is what happens when two documents (let's say two identical versions of the XML i presented in the beginning of my question) are merged:

```
    <chapter title="This is first chapter">
        <section title="This is the first section">
        <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
        </section>
<chapter title="This is second chapter">
        <section title="This is the first section">
        <paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the paragraph content</paragraph>
        </section>
        </chapter>
        </chapter>
```

I think the reason for this problem, is that there are no root element for the merged documents. So, is there for example a way to add a `<doc>` tag or something for the merged XML's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at it from another view point. You create a new document that combines all the chapters of you book. So create a book element and import the chapters into it.

```
// create a new document
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// and add the root element
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('book'));

// for each document/xml to add
foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
  // create a dom
  $addDom = new DOMDocument();
  // load the chapter
  $addDom->load($chapter);
  // if here is a root node in the loaded xml
  if ($addDom->documentElement) {
    // append to the result dom
    $dom->documentElement->appendChild(
      // after importing the document element to the result dom
      $dom->importNode($addDom->documentElement, TRUE)
    );
  }
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```